# Close side loaded office add-in on excel online?

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-js

I'm working on an Excel Task-pane Add-In, and have side loaded it on Excel Online following the instructions on [Sideload an Office Add-In on Microsoft Office Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt657708.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

The Add-In is successfully loaded, nevertheless, I can't find a way to close/unload it.

On Excel for Mac, a close button is available at the top right corner of the task-pane, but no such button exists on Excel Online.

I`ve already tried to log out and close the browser, but it didn't work.

May you please help on that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In Office Online, add-ins can't be closed, they can only be "collapsed". However, it's worth noting that even when you "close" add-ins in desktop Office, they remain loaded in the document or your user account.

You can remove add-ins by going to Insert > Office Add-ins/My Add-ins and clicking on the "..." on an add-in in tile and selecting Remove. For add-ins that are sideloaded in Office Online, they are stored in the browser's localStorage, so clearing the localStorage will remove them.

Comment: Hi Harrison, thank you very much for your reply.  I've tried clearing browser local storage but it didn't remove the add-in (I'm using chrome on mac). It looks like the information is stored on the document itself. The workaround I've been using is to open the document on Office desktop, close the add-in, save the document and then open it on Office Online (this makes the add-in not to be shown, so that I may sideload it again). Still, this is not practical, and I can't understand why the same close button available on Office desktop is not there on Office Online.

Answer (score 0):

The information on what add-ins are loaded is saved together with the document itself. If you open an documented that has been saved with the add-in opened, you (or anyone really) will see this add-in again on opening. If you're talking about the uploaded add-in in the add-in catalog, the add-ins uploaded there should not be saved at all (other than in the document maybe). The add-ins listed there are sourced from the add-in catalog that your Office tenant admin provides.

Hope this helps,
Jesse

Comment: Hi Jesse, thank you very much for your reply. Indeed, I'm still facing the same issue: an add-in once side loaded on Office Online will stay there forever. I mean, after I side load an add-in that I`ve developed to test it on office online, I can't find any way to unload it...